# How to make one function that organizes multiple NSURLSessionDataTask (s)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

After creating an NSURLSession, it appears that making multiple web queries with NSURLSessionDataTask can lead to some code writing redundancy, which I'd like to clean up. The following code is repeated multiple times:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
}];
[task resume];
```

Could the task be initiated from inside a dedicated function? It would be easy to pass in the NSMutableURLRequest as a variable but what about the completion handler?

Theoretically you could pass in the completion handler as a block, right? The problem I ran into is that the callback variables (data & response) can't be referred to from outside the provided completion handler, so how can you write a block that refers to them?

Right now I have 3 or 4 separately written tasks going, and it looks like it may stay that way unless someone has an idea!

EDIT, SOLUTION:

The method definition is:

```
- (void) engage:(NSMutableURLRequest *)request with:(void (^)(NSData *, NSURLResponse *, NSError *))yourmom;
```

& The block literal that it takes looks like:

```
void (^yourmom)(NSData *, NSURLResponse *, NSError *) = ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
// stuff
};
```

Basically, the key thing I was missing was that I needed my block to accept variables so that I could refer to them by name without compiler errors. The above code creates a variable-accepting block which lets me get around the compiler warnings about out of scope variables. Also if the code 
    [self engage:request with:yourmom];
shows up somewhere we'll know where it came from.

Comment: I'm a little unsure as to what specifically you are trying to achieve. Please clarify and i'll do my best to help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how can you pass the completion block to the utility method, you should just supply a block parameter to your method:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)startDataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))block
{
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:block];
    [task resume];

    return task;
}
```

Or, if there are portions of the completion block which you're repeating all the time, then go ahead and put that in your utility method, but then invoke the caller's block:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)startDataTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(void (^)(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))block
{
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
        // do here stuff that I'll always do, such as logging errors, checking response codes, etc.

        // when that's done, I can now invoke the caller's block

        if (block) {
            block(data, response, error);
        }
    }];
    [task resume];

    return task;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! You nailed it hard. Your first example answered a vital half of my question. I was able to figure out the syntax of the block literal from there. Also, great suggestion about leaving an area for routine work. That's where I'd be headed next but so far no common work to do right there. May I ask why you decided to return your task and what you're planning on doing with it?

Comment: @neptune You want to return the task so that (a) you can identify failures in creating the task (e.g. a bad URL); and (b) if you want to cancel the task later (e.g. you might want to cancel the task if the user dismisses the relevant view controller), you have the task pointer.

Comment: So sooner or later you'll have a bunch of tasks piling up, probably from different methods. Would you create a method to organize those? Or would you need to then create an organizer of the organizers, leading to a mind-bending infinite regression?

Comment: @neptune No, offense, but I think you're making this more complicated than you need. No infinite regression. Personally, I always wrap my `NSURLSessionTask` objects in operations, something that is pretty easy if using `completionHandler` based requests, but a bit of a bear if you're using `delegate` based requests. Then I use `NSOperationQueue` with `maxConcurrentOperationCount` of 4 or 5 as the mechanism for coordinating the requests. If you don't, you risk having later requests timeout if they get too backlogged behind a bunch of other requests (notably on slow connections).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say make a category on NSURLSession and do the following:

First typedef a completion block in the header file:

```
typedef void (^NSURLSessionDataTaskCompletionHandler) (NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error);
```

Then add a method to the header file:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)startTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(NSURLSessionDataTaskCompletionHandler)completionHandler;
```

Finally the body of the function in the implementation file:

```
- (NSURLSessionDataTask *)startTaskWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request completionHandler:(NSURLsessionDataTaskCompletionHandler)completionHandler
{
    NSURLSessionDataTask *task = [self dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:completionHandler];
    [task resume];
    return task;
}
```

Now you get to very easily do something like:

```
[session startTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
    // do stuff
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! You both nailed it, but I like your typedef - definitely cleans things up compared to the other comment. May I ask why you wanted to return the task? Also I'm not well-versed in categories and I don't understand the effect of making the NSURLSession a category. What's the benefit of that?

Comment: Both good questions. I'm returning the task because there are useful properties associated with an NSURLSessionDataTask that you may want to take advantage of aside from simply starting the task. Also, no harm in returning it. You don't have do anything with it you do not want to.

Comment: As for categories, they allow you to add methods to built in classes (or any class actually) without subclassing that class. This is extremely useful for classes that you would never bother subclassing, like NSString, but want to do a lot of different operations on that Apple does not provide. [Apple Category Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)